# TOR Hanging after closed down

Tags: connection

Windows 10 (1809).  TOR Version 8.0.6. TOR works perfectly after system starts. If then closed down and re-opened just hangs. Only works again after system re-booted,

Comment: Can you give more details? How far does it get before it hangs? Can you click on anything, or is the GUI frozen?

Comment: The page loads but done of the buttons are operative. After a short while the Tor header says "not responding" and hangs.  Page then has to be closed.

Comment: The debug report can be found at : https://drop.me/MvxX7Y